# Jar cannot find file?

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I am working on a project and i am trying to set the icon for the frame.  I debug it in eclipse and it works fine without a problem but when I go to export it, it does not find the image when i run the jar file.

Here is my try/catch

```
try {
frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("res/Icon.png")));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my file structure.

[image]

Comment: `new File("res/Icon.png")` reads a **file**, on the **file system**, in `<current directory>/res/Icon.png`. Use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(). There are dozens of question about that.

Comment: That didn't fix it, it stopped it from working in eclipse.

Comment: Because res is not marked as a source directory. Or because you screwed up. Put the images with your source files, under a package. If they're in package foo.bar, then load them using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("foo/bar/image.png").